# LWC tree-grid rows not expanding

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

I'm building a lighting web component that displays hierarchal data. Its wrapped in an aura component. The issue I've encountered and am stumped on is expanding a single row that has children. The chevron icon is acting as if it's disabled. However, I can see the data in the console.

I tried using the ontoggle action to get the row details but I can't even get anything to log to the console. I thought maybe the chevron icon not loading the next row was due to the lwc being inside of an aura but I can get two buttons on the lwc to Expand All or Collapse All. Can anyone provide some guidance on what I'm missing?

Console view
[image]

````
  <lightning-card title="Hierarchy">
   <div class="slds-float_right">
     <lightning-button label="Collapse" onclick={clickToCollapseAll}> </lightning-button>
     <lightning-button label="Expand" onclick={clickToExpandAll}> </lightning-button>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
      <lightning-tree-grid columns={columns}
                           data={treeItems}
                           key-field="name"
                           ontoggle={handleRowToggle}>
       </lightning-tree-grid>
     </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>

import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getHierarchy from '@salesforce/apex/HierarchyController.getHierarchy'; 

export default class Hierarchy extends LightningElement {
    iconName = 'standard:outcome';
    @api recordId;
    @track coiId;
    @track error;
    @track treeItems;
     
     @track columns = [
       {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'FullName',
            label: 'Full Name'
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'Tier',
            label: 'Tier'
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'Title',
            label: 'Title'
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'Email',
            label: 'Email'
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'Phone',
            label: 'Phone'
        }
    ];

@wire(getHierarchy, {recId : '$recordId'})
    wiredHierarchies({ error, data }){
        if (data){
            var res = data;
            console.log('res data '+res);
            var tempjson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).split('items').join('_children'));
            console.log('tempjson '+tempjson);
            console.log('data items '+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).split('items')));
            this.treeItems = tempjson;
            console.log('json stringified '+JSON.stringify(tempjson, null, '\t'));
         } else {
            this.error = error;
            //alert('error ' + error);
        }
    }
                                
clickToExpandAll( e ) {
  const grid =  this.template.querySelector( 'lightning-tree-grid' );
  grid.expandAll();
}

clickToCollapseAll( e ) {
  const grid =  this.template.querySelector( 'lightning-tree-grid' );
  grid.collapseAll();
}

handleRowToggle(event) {
        // let rowId = event.target.dataset.rowid;
        // let isExpanded = event.target.dataset.expanded;
        // event.target.iconName = JSON.parse(isExpanded) ? "utility:chevronright": "utility:chevrondown";
        // event.target.dataset.expanded = JSON.stringify(!JSON.parse(isExpanded));
         
        // this.treeItems = this.treeItems.map((obj) => {
        //  if(obj.parentId == rowId &&  !JSON.parse(isExpanded)){
        //      obj.rowStyle = "";
        //  }
        //  if(obj.parentId == rowId && JSON.parse(isExpanded)){
        //      obj.rowStyle = "hide";
        //  }
        //  return obj;
        // });
        // console.log(this.treeItems);
        // console.log('handleRowToggle called');
        // const eventName = 'rowToggle';

        // this.rowId = event.detail.row.Id;
        // console.log('rowName '+this.rowId);
        // console.log('row: ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail.row));

        const rowName = event.detail.name;
        console.log('rowName '+rowName);
        // const row = event.detail.row;
        // console.log('row '+row);
        // const hasChildrenContent = event.detail.hasChildrenContent;
        // console.log('hasChildrenContent '+hasChildrenContent);

        // if (!hasChildrenContent) {
        //     this.treeItems = getNewDataWithChildren(rowName, this.treeItems, newChildren);
        // }

        // this.rowValue = event.detail.isExpanded;
        // console.log('rowName '+rowValue);

        // const rowToggleEvent = new CustomEvent('rowtoggle', {
        //    detail: {rowName},
        // });
        // this.dispatchEvent(rowToggleEvent);

        // console.log( 'Selected Sections ' + event.detail.openSections);
        // const isExpanded = event.detail.isExpanded;
        // console.log('isExpanded '+isExpanded);

        // const hasChildrenContent = event.detail.hasChildrenContent;

        // if (!hasChildrenContent) {
        //     this.data = getNewDataWithChildren(rowName, this.data, newChildren);
        // }
        
        
        // const isExpanded = event.detail.isExpanded;
        // console.log('isExpanded '+isExpanded);
        // isExpanded = true;
        
        // retrieve the unique identifier of the row being expanded
        // const rowName = event.detail.name;
        // console.log('rowName '+rowName);
        // does the component have children content for this row already?
        // const hasChildrenContent = event.detail.hasChildrenContent;
        // console.log('hasChildrenContent '+hasChildrenContent);

        // the new expanded state for this row
        // const isExpanded = event.detail.isExpanded;
        // console.log('isExpanded '+isExpanded);

        /*
        ** additional event.detail values available:
        **
        ** => the new expanded state for this row
        **    const isExpanded = event.detail.isExpanded;
        **
        ** => the complete row data
        **    const row = event.detail.row;
        */
        
        // if hasChildrenContent is false then we need to react and add children
        // if (hasChildrenContent === false) {
        //     this.gridLoadingState = true;

        //     // call a method to retrieve the updated data tree that includes the missing children
        //     this.retrieveUpdatedData(rowName).then(newData => {
        //         this.gridData = newData;
        //         this.gridLoadingState = false;
        //     });
        // }
}```
````

Comment: Your `tempjson` probably doesn't match the expected data format to show children. Your line beginning with `var tempjson` looks strange and could be related. Make sure to log tempjson and verify the data structure is what you expect

Comment: Thanks @AndyRay, I'll debug starting from there.

Comment: @AndyRay I'm using a wrapper class like here: https://rajvakati.com/2018/12/30/lightning-web-component-tree-grid/#respond. The only difference is I have 4 levels of children vs 1. All records are showing the same fields. The one thing I noticed in the json is _children are placed in between the field values (FullName and RecordId/ParentId) of the branch/parent. Could this be causing the issue? If so, then I assume I need to set the order.

Comment: this ended up being a small mistake on the lightning-tree-grid component's key-field. The variable name was incorrect.